# Ruby on Rails: RestAuth: how do I log out using HTTPS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, https, restful-authentication

```
<%= link_to("Log Out", session_url, :method => :delete) %>
```

When I am on a non https page logging out works fine.

But the issue is when I am on an https page, the above code throws an error

```
Parameters: {"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"sessions"}

ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded to show. Actions: create, destroy, forgot, reset, and set_time_zone):
```

I tried changing session_url to new_session_url, but then I got an error saying only GET requests were allowed

Any idea how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at this question: 
[Add a logout button in RESTFUL authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166635/add-a-logout-button-in-restful-authentication)